# More efficient way of duplicating the code

Tags: javascript, html

Every time I click the + button I want the same input to display

[image: So it looks like this]

The way I do it here works fine but seems like the worst way of doing it as just repeating the same code and changing the id's (also if I want for example 5 inputs I would have to repeat this code 5 times). What would be a better way of doing this?

```
<html>
<head>

 <script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>

    function show3(){
    document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'block';
     }


</script>

<style>

   .hide {
   display: none;
   }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>

    <input type="range" min="0" max="1500" value="0" class="slider2" id="one"/>

    <p>Value(mm): <input type="text" id="two" size="10" class="special" /></p>

    <button onclick="show3();" type="button">+</button>


</div> 

<script>
    var slider1 = document.getElementById("one");
    var output2 = document.getElementById("two");
    output2.value = slider1.value;

    slider1.oninput = function() {
    output2.value = this.value;
    }
</script>


<div id="div2" class="hide">

    <input type="range" min="0" max="1500" value="0" class="slider2" id="three"/>

    <p>Value(mm): <input type="text" id="four" size="10" class="special" /></p>

    <button onclick="show3();" type="button">+</button>


</div> 

<script>
    var slider2 = document.getElementById("three");
    var output3 = document.getElementById("four");
    output2.value = slider1.value;

    slider2.oninput = function() {
    output3.value = this.value;
    }
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

```html
<html>
<head>



<script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>

 function show3(){
   document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'block';
 }


</script>
<style>
 .hide {
  display: none;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>




 <div>
 
 <input type="range" min="0" max="1500" value="0" class="slider2" id="one"/>

     <p>Value(mm): <input type="text" id="two" size="10" class="special" /></p>
 
  <button onclick="show3();" type="button">+</button>


 </div> 
 
 <script>
 var slider1 = document.getElementById("one");
 var output2 = document.getElementById("two");
 output2.value = slider1.value;

 slider1.oninput = function() {
   output2.value = this.value;
 }
 </script>

 
  <div id="div2" class="hide">
 
 <input type="range" min="0" max="1500" value="0" class="slider2" id="three"/>

     <p>Value(mm): <input type="text" id="four" size="10" class="special" /></p>
 
  <button onclick="show3();" type="button">+</button>


 </div> 
 
 <script>
 var slider2 = document.getElementById("three");
 var output3 = document.getElementById("four");
 output2.value = slider1.value;

 slider2.oninput = function() {
   output3.value = this.value;
 }
 </script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please create a working snippet, would be very helpful.

Comment: Your question isn't really worded correctly.  You aren't trying to "duplicate your code", you are trying to create a button that creates duplicate HTML elements.  Quite a different thing, actually....

Comment: You are trying to create code that writes code and appends it to current page right?

Comment: sorry, I'm new to stack overflow, I think I added the snippet, essentially what I want is when you click the + button the same thing displays again so I get the slider and value:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for all the sliders. But you need to keep in mind a couple of things :

1. This will work only for the sliders that are already rendered in the DOM (even if they are hidden) if you render new sliders to the DOM you will need to attach the event listener as I did it in the foreach loop.
2. The input id (e.g "one") needs to match the output `data-range="one"`

```js
function show3(){
  document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'block';
}

var sliders = document.querySelectorAll(".slider"); // slider = common class name
sliders.forEach(( slider ) => {
  slider.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    const sliderId = e.target.id;
    const output = document.querySelector(`[data-range=${sliderId}]`);
    output.value = e.target.value;
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
   .hide {
     display: none;
   }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="1500" value="0" class="slider" id="one"/>
    <p>Value(mm): <input type="text" data-range="one" id="two" size="10" class="special" /></p>
    <button onclick="show3();" type="button">+</button>
</div> 

<div id="div2" class="hide">

    <input type="range" min="0" max="1500" value="0" class="slider" id="two"/>
    <p>Value(mm): <input type="text" data-range="two" id="four" size="10" class="special" /></p>
    <button onclick="show3();" type="button">+</button>

</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused on how it works but ill go over it step by step. Anyway, it works great and looks much better than mine, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to include the code in the element and clone it (parentNode is the div) :

```html
<div>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="1500" value="0" 
      oninput="this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('INPUT')[1].value = this.value"/>
    <p>Value(mm): <input type="text" size="10" /></p>
    <button type="button" 
      onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.append(this.parentNode.cloneNode(true))">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What you are doing is very tricky and not very "clean" in my opinion. You are navigating through the DOM (parent nodes) assuming the input text will be always a sibling. If he wraps the input in a div for styling, voila! your script will fail.

Comment: That's pretty cool, it works even better and I can duplicate it as many times as I want without creating more divs, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to create some kind of class which let you create slider components dynamically.

Here's a quick example (not optimized):

```js
var SliderComponent = (function(doc) {
  var defaults = {
    containerSelector: 'body',
    value: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 1500,
    inputSize: 10,
    inputClass: 'special',
    sliderClass: 'slider',
    buttonClass: 'button'
  }, options;

  function SliderComponent(options) {
    options = Object.assign({}, defaults, options || {});
    this.container = getContainer(options);
    this.input = createInput(options);
    this.slider = createSlider(options);
    this.removeButton = createButton(options.buttonClass, '-');
    this.addButton = createButton(options.buttonClass, '+');
    this.element = render.apply(this);
    this.events = [];
    
    this.events.push(
      addEventListener.call(this, 'click', this.removeButton, function() {
        this.destroy();
      }),
      addEventListener.call(this, 'click', this.addButton, function() {
        new SliderComponent(options);
      }),
      addEventListener.call(this, 'input', this.slider, function(event) {
        this.input.value = event.target.value;
      }),
      addEventListener.call(this, 'input', this.input, function(event) {
        this.slider.value = event.target.value;
      })
    )
  }
  
  SliderComponent.prototype.destroy = function() {
    this.events.forEach(function(e) {
      e();
    });
    this.element.remove();
  }
  
  function addEventListener(name, element, listener) {
    listener = listener.bind(this);
    element.addEventListener(name, listener);
    return function() {
      element.removeEventListener(name, listener);
    };
  } 
  
  function getContainer(options) {
    var container = doc.querySelector(options.containerSelector);
    if(!container) {
      throw new Error('Container for selector %s not found', options.containerSelector);
    }
    return container;
  }
  
  function createInput(options) {
    var input = doc.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'number');
    input.setAttribute('min', options.min);
    input.setAttribute('max', options.max);
    input.setAttribute('size', options.inputSize);
    input.classList.add(options.inputClass);
    input.value = options.value;
    return input;
  }
  
  function createSlider(options) {
    var input = doc.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'range');
    input.setAttribute('min', options.min);
    input.setAttribute('max', options.max);
    input.classList.add(options.sliderClass);
    input.value = options.value;
    return input;
  }
  
  function createButton(klass, text) {
    var button = doc.createElement('button');
    button.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    button.classList.add(klass);
    button.textContent = text;
    return button;
  }
  
  function render() {
    var element = doc.createElement('div');
    element.appendChild(this.slider);
    element.appendChild(this.input);
    element.appendChild(this.removeButton);
    element.appendChild(this.addButton);
    return this.container.appendChild(element);
  }
  
  return SliderComponent;
})(document);

var sliders = new SliderComponent();
```